# Need a zip of Python 2.6 for windows

Tags: python, zip

Not the source codes, thats the only thing i seem to find. I can't install py2.6 because it would overtake 2.5 and cause mayor mess in my pc.

Comment: you can always install 2.6 and then 2.5 :)

Comment: -1: Need zip, but can't install it?  What does "need" mean if you can't actually use it?

Comment: he needs a zipped python, you misunderstood something

Comment: @Nikola: The OP says he need a zipped Python. He doesn't. S.Lott's question (and mine) is what does the OP think he is going to DO with the non-existent non-source-code zip that he thinks he needs, that can't be done with the Windows installer. And another question is why the OP doesn't just say what his real problem is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How would it overtake 2.5? You can install both in parallel, just make sure that you unselect the option to "Register Extensions" during the install of 2.6.

I have several Python installations on my PC in parallel, one of them my "standard" one that I expect to run when I doubleclick on a `.py` file, and the other one to invoke manually if I need it.

I have found, though, that sometimes file associations are lost completely after installing a new version without the "Register Extensions" option set. In that case just run a "repair installation" with your preferred standard version, and you should be good to go.

Comment: This is exactly what I have found.

Comment: i just checked, there's no file association option in the installer

Comment: We're talking about the Windows installer? I just checked, the option is in fact called "Register Extensions". I will edit my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I have Pythons 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, and 3.1 all installed on my PC.  Download the .msi from python.org, and install it.

Comment: How do you get your scripts to run on the correct interpreter? I stopped working with 2.5 but would love to run those old programs before porting them over to 3.1.

Comment: One of them is the one registered as handling .py files, so I can just run those directly.  If I need to use a specific version, I start a new command shell, set the PATH to point to the proper Python version, then use "python myprog.py" to run it explicitly.

Comment: or you can do it in the SAME command window by typing (for example) `\python21\python myprog.py`

Comment: Yes, I use a new cmd window because usually when I have to change Python versions, I also need to make other changes, the Python path for example, or environment variables for django settings, whatever.  I've just gotten in the habit of starting new cmds for new environments.