# How to set python enviroment variable on windows

Tags: python

I've downloaded python installer from http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.1.2/ , this `python-3.1.2.msi` file, I need to execute some python files? How do I do that? For example in php I'd do php filename.php from console, I do however have python command line but I don't know how to execute those files.

So if I could set ENV variable to directly execute my file(s) if that is possible that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option in the installer called "Register Extensions" to associate Python files with the interpreter, so double-clicking them or entering `filename.py` in the console should work.

Apart from that you might want to add `C:\Python31` to your `PATH` variable (right-click on My Computer, choose Settings, choose the Advanced Tab - there you can access the system variables. Better do this as an admin.

Comment: I've added it to the path now, but I get some compile errors is it possible that I've downloaded wrong version of the language?

Answer (score 0):

If you type `python` in the Windows command line, what happens? Is the Python interpreter in your `PATH` yet?

If not, add the Python installation directory there (here's a [good guide](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)). Then just do `python script.py` just like with PHP.

Comment: I've added it to the path now, but I get some compile errors is it possible that I've downloaded wrong version of the language?

Comment: Python 3 is incompatible with Python 2. If you're getting runtime errors (hard to get compile errors in Python), you might be running a Python 2 script. A good sign are `print` statements - if the syntax used is `print "Hello"` instead of `print("Hello")`, then it's a Python 2 script.
You can have both versions installed in parallel.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker its like this in the file `print "    list                            - Print summary of existing objects by class"` so its version 2 of the language?

Comment: Yes it is. Download version 2.6.5 and install it in a different directory - see also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835930

Answer (score 0):

you can just execute
`python yourfile.py`

Or if the python command don't work you have to give the absolute path to you python installation or add it to windows path